# Delphi Get return value when running a dos command using ShellExec

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

If I execute the following command in a command/dos window

```
schtasks.exe /delete /tn "MMP4CDownloadCheck" /f
```

the result is as follows

```
ERROR: The specified task name "MMP4CDownloadCheck" does not exist in the system.
```

Is it possible to retrieve the return value(s) when running the same command from within my application (Delphi XE) using `ShellExec`?

I run it as follows:

```
AHWnd := ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('schtasks.exe'), PChar(Params), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards, Pieter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Possibly with [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need to call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and for that you need the handle of the created process.

For your specific case, perhaps it's better to avoid calling `schtasks.exe` and use the [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead. See `JclTask` in the [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/).

An example usage I've found in one of my old units (for Delphi 2007):

```
procedure TSetupDataModule.AddDatabaseBackupTask;
var
  FileName: WideString;
  Scheduler: ITaskScheduler;
  Task: ITask;
  TaskPersist: IPersistFile;
  TriggerIndex: Word;
  Trigger: ITaskTrigger;
  TriggerData: TTaskTrigger;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskScheduler, Scheduler));
  OleCheck(Scheduler.NewWorkItem(BackupTaskName, CLSID_CTask, IID_ITask, IUnknown(Task)));

  FileName := WideIncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(FDatabaseTargetDir) + BackupToolFileName;
  OleCheck(Task.SetApplicationName(PWideChar(FileName)));

  OleCheck(Task.SetWorkingDirectory(PWideChar(WideExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(FDatabaseTargetDir))));
  OleCheck(Task.SetAccountInformation('', nil)); // run as local system

  FillChar(TriggerData, SizeOf(TriggerData), 0);
  TriggerData.cbTriggerSize := SizeOf(TriggerData);
  TriggerData.wBeginYear := YearOf(Today);
  TriggerData.wBeginMonth := MonthOf(Today);
  TriggerData.wBeginDay := DayOf(Today);
  TriggerData.wStartHour := 0;
  TriggerData.wStartMinute := 0;
  TriggerData.rgFlags := 0;
  TriggerData.TriggerType := TASK_TIME_TRIGGER_DAILY;
  TriggerData.Type_.Daily.DaysInterval := 1;

  OleCheck(Task.CreateTrigger(TriggerIndex, Trigger));
  OleCheck(Trigger.SetTrigger(@TriggerData));

  TaskPersist := Task as IPersistFile;
  OleCheck(TaskPersist.Save(nil, True));
end;

procedure TSetupDataModule.RemoveDatabaseBackupTask;
var
  Scheduler: ITaskScheduler;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskScheduler, Scheduler));
  OleCheck(Scheduler.Delete(BackupTaskName));
end;
```

Comment: I do find the `schtasks.exe` more appealing as it creates tasks that are visible from the Scheduled Tasks app in Windows. I suppose JclTask would be better for Delphi. Do you know of any examples that shows how to use it in an application?

Comment: If you use the API the tasks will appear in the Scheduled Tasks app in Windows. The app uses the API, too. I'll add an example in a moment.